# MS Project 2016 - Calendar View Customizing

Tags: ms-project

I'm using MS Projects 2016 Standard Version (on-premise). I did some searches on this topic but didn't get an easy solution. Hence I'm creating this question.

MS Project Calendar View intend to offer visualization to team members. However, it would be much better if we can customize the view for even more easy viewing. Can any expert help me with below?

1. enable different color for different bar
2. enable text formula in bar text, e.g. "Summary Task Name" & "-" & "Task Name" & "-" & "Subtask Name", etc. right now, I only see the possibility of selecting text from a drop down list, I can manually adjust the text order but it can be more user friendlier.

Other PM tools, e.g. Smart Sheet, already offers such features with ease of use but our project uses MS Project 2016.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using Project Online or on-premise?  And which version: standard, pro....? The available features will change depending on what you are using. I don't have Project 2016 installed, but here are options:

- Did you use the Format tab and look at the options under Bar Styles and also the options when you right click on the bar you want to change?
- Project 2016 also has pre-built templates and reports that will likely give you the view(s) you need without the text formula.
- Another option is to make sure you have given your tasks descriptive names so that you can view them and differentiate which from which. In Project I rely on a good naming structure so I can easily identify tasks.  For example under a Summary Task like "Development" I will put Dev at the beginning of the task name (Dev.code web CSS). This also helps when viewing as it sorts related tasks together.
- In the MS Store, there are a wide variety of add-ins to Project, perhaps one will provide what you are looking for:  https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=project, check the Analytics box on the left.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question, Gaby. But since you don't have

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question, Gaby. I've updated the original post so future volunteers won't ask the same valid question - I'm using MS Projects 2016 Standard Version (on-premise). However, since you don't have MS Project 2016 installed and just offered generic suggestions, I did not find your suggestions providing immediate help. Thanks again for your willingness to try.